# If $n$ is a positive whole number, write this in the form $a+ b\sqrt{3}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $n$ is a positive whole number, write $(n\sqrt{15} - \sqrt{5})^{2}$ in the form $(a + b\sqrt{3})$.

Please help! I can't cancel out the n to write it in this form!

Comment: You don't need to cancel $n$. You need to cancel $\sqrt5$.

Answer (score 1):

$(n\sqrt{15}-\sqrt{5})^2 = 15n^2 +5 - 2 n \sqrt{15} \sqrt{5} = 15n^2+5-2n \sqrt{25*3} = 15n^2+5-2n *5 \sqrt{3} = 15n^2+5-10 n \sqrt{3}$ ,

take $a=15n^2+5$ and $b=-10n$.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note
$$
\sqrt{15} = \sqrt{5 \times 3} = \sqrt{5} \times \sqrt{3}
$$
So with this in mind
$$
(n\sqrt{15} -\sqrt{5})^2 = (n\sqrt{5}\times\sqrt{3} -\sqrt{5})^2 
$$
Factoring the $\sqrt{5}$ we find
$$
(n\sqrt{3} - 1)^2\sqrt{5}^2 = 5(n\sqrt{3}-1)^2
$$
Now lets expand the brackets
$$
(n\sqrt{3}-1)^2 = n^23 -2n\sqrt{3} +  1 = (3n^2 + 1) - 2n\sqrt{3}
$$
Finally we multiply by $5$ to find (and if you are careful in multiplying by $5$)
$$
5(3n^2+1) - 10n\sqrt{3}
$$
Comparing terms with the original requirement of $a + b\sqrt{3}$
We find
$$
a = 5(3n^2+1) \\
b = -10n
$$

Comment: Multiplying what you have as a result for "expanding the brackets, by 5, gives $$5(3n^2+1) - 10n\sqrt 3$$

Comment: @amWhy I am not entirely sure why I even did that, maybe I was thinking multiply by $3$.